# uploadig adobe reader file in local host in c language

Tags: c

> I am uploading adobe files in local host it is uploading file successfully but it is showing corrupt or damage file after opening file please help me out to sort out this problem i will be thankful to you below is my entire code

```
int main()
{
WIN32_FIND_DATA fdFile;
HANDLE hFind = NULL;

TCHAR sPath[2048];
char sDir[2048]= "C:\\boot\\config\\";

//Specify a file mask. *.* = We want everything!

sprintf(sPath, "%s\\*.*", sDir);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if((hFind = FindFirstFile(sPath, &fdFile)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Path not found: [%s]\n", sDir);
    return false;
}
do
{
   //Find first file will always return "."
    //    and ".." as the first two directories.
    if(strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, ".") != 0
            && strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, "..") != 0)
    {
        sprintf(sPath, "%s\\%s", sDir, fdFile.cFileName);
 if(fdFile.dwFileAttributes &FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            printf("Directory: %s\n", sPath);

        }
        else{
            printf("%s\n", sPath);
static char *type = "text/pdf";
static TCHAR hdrs[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d82751e2bc0858";
static char boundary[] = "-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858";            //Header boundary
static char nameForm[] = "uploadedfile";     //Input form name
static char iaddr[] = "localhost";        //IP address
static char url[] = "/xampp/testing/upload.php?folder=aaaa&&foldername=bbbb";

char * buffer;                   //Buffer containing file + headers
char * content;                  //Buffer containing file
FILE * pFile;                    //File pointer
long lSize;                      //File size
size_t result;
char *pos; // used in the loop

// Open file
pFile = fopen(filepath, "rb");
if (pFile == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR_OPEN_FILE");
    getchar();
    return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
}
printf("OPEN_FILE\n");

// obtain file size:
fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell(pFile);
rewind(pFile);

// allocate memory to contain the whole file:
content = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
if (content == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR_MEMORY");
    getchar();
    return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
}
 printf("MEMORY_ALLOCATED\t \"%d\" \n", lSize);
// copy the file into the buffer:
result = fread(content, 1, lSize, pFile);

rewind (pFile);

if (result != lSize)
{
    printf("ERROR_SIZE");
    getchar();
    return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
}
printf("SIZE_OK\n");

// terminate
fclose(pFile);
printf("FILE_CLOSE\n");
//allocate memory to contain the whole file + HEADER
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048);

   //print header

sprintf(buffer, "%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%s\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n", boundary, nameForm, filename);
sprintf(buffer, "%sContent-Type: %s\r\n", buffer, type);
sprintf(buffer, "%sContent-Length: %d\r\n", buffer, lSize);
strcat(buffer, "\r\n");
int len= strlen(buffer);
memcpy(buffer + len, content, lSize);
char *buf_tail= buffer+len+lSize;
strcpy(buf_tail, "\r\n");
buf_tail += 2; 
strcpy(buf_tail, boundary);
buf_tail += strlen(boundary);
strcpy(buf_tail, "--\r\n");

//Open internet connection
HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("WINDOWS", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
if (hSession == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN");
    getchar();
    return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
}
printf("INTERNET_OPENED\n");

HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, iaddr, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
if (hConnect == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR_INTERNET_CONN");
    getchar();
    return ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;
}
printf("INTERNET_CONNECTED\n");

HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST", _T(url), NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 1);
if (hRequest == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR_INTERNET_REQ");
    getchar();

}
printf("INTERNET_REQ_OPEN\n");

BOOL sent = HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buf_tail, strlen(buf_tail));

if (!sent)
{
    printf("ERROR_INTERNET_SEND");
    getchar();
    return ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;
}
printf("INTERNET_SEND_OK\n");
printf("\r\n%s\r\n",buffer);

//close any valid internet-handles
InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
 }
 }
 }
while(FindNextFile(hFind, &fdFile));
FindClose(hFind); //clean things up!
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your last comment to my previous answer, you probably ran out of memory. There are also other errors. The following function should be correct:

(note: using strict C and TCHARS removed as I don't use those)

```
#define ERROR_OPEN_FILE       10
#define ERROR_MEMORY          11
#define ERROR_SIZE            12
#define ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN   13
#define ERROR_INTERNET_CONN   14
#define ERROR_INTERNET_REQ    15
#define ERROR_INTERNET_SEND   16
#define ERROR_NO_PATH         17
#define ERROR_FINDNEXT        18

int InetPDF(void)   // returns 0 upon success
{
    static char *type = "text/pdf";
    static char hdrs[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d82751e2bc0858";
    static char boundary[] = "-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858";            //Header boundary
    static char nameForm[] = "uploadedfile";     //Input form name
    static char iaddr[] = "localhost";        //IP address
    static char url[] = "/xampp/testing/upload.php?folder=aaaa&&foldername=bbbb";

    char *buffer;       // Buffer containing file + headers
    FILE *pFile;        // File pointer
    long lSize;         // File size
    int len, sent, retval= 0;
    char *buf_tail;
    HINTERNET hSession=0, hConnect=0, hRequest=0;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fdFile;
    HANDLE hFind = NULL;
    char sPath[2048];
    char sDir[]= "C:\\boot\\config";

    sprintf(sPath, "%s\\*.*", sDir);

    if ((hFind = FindFirstFile(sPath, &fdFile)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Path not found: [%s]\n", sDir);
        return ERROR_NO_PATH;
    }
    do
    {
        if ((fdFile.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)==0)
        {
            sprintf(sPath, "%s\\%s", sDir, fdFile.cFileName);

            // Open file
            if ((pFile = fopen(sPath, "rb")) == NULL)
            {
                printf("ERROR_OPEN_FILE");
                return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
            }
            // obtain file size:
            fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
            lSize = ftell(pFile);
            rewind(pFile);

            //allocate memory to contain the whole file + HEADER and trailer
            if ((buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048))== NULL)
            {
                printf("ERROR_MEMORY");
                fclose(pFile);
                return ERROR_MEMORY;
            }
            // create the header
            sprintf(buffer, "%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%s\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n", boundary, nameForm, fdFile.cFileName);
            sprintf(buffer, "%sContent-Type: %s\r\n", buffer, type);
            sprintf(buffer, "%sContent-Length: %d\r\n", buffer, lSize);
            strcat(buffer, "\r\n");
            len= strlen(buffer);

            // read the file into the buffer:
            if (fread(buffer + len, 1, lSize, pFile) != lSize)
            {
                printf("ERROR_SIZE");
                fclose(pFile);
                retval= ERROR_SIZE;
                goto cleanup;
            }
            fclose(pFile);

            // create the trailer
            buf_tail= buffer+len+lSize;
            strcpy(buf_tail, "\r\n");
            strcat(buf_tail, boundary);
            strcat(buf_tail, "--\r\n");

            // Open internet connection
            if ((hSession = InternetOpen("WINDOWS", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0)) == NULL)
            {
                printf("ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN");
                retval= ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN;
                goto cleanup;
            }
            if ((hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, iaddr, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1)) == NULL)
            {
                printf("ERROR_INTERNET_CONN");
                retval= ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;
                goto cleanup;
            }
            if ((hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST", url, NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 1))  == NULL)
            {
                printf("ERROR_INTERNET_REQ");
                retval= ERROR_INTERNET_REQ;
                goto cleanup;
            }
            if ((sent = HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buffer, len+lSize+strlen(buf_tail))) == 0)
            {
                printf("ERROR_INTERNET_SEND");
                retval= ERROR_INTERNET_SEND;
                goto cleanup;
            }
          cleanup:
            if (hSession) {InternetCloseHandle(hSession); hSession= 0;}
            if (hConnect) {InternetCloseHandle(hConnect); hConnect= 0;}
            if (hRequest) {InternetCloseHandle(hRequest); hRequest= 0;}
            free(buffer);
            if (retval!=0) {
                break;  // an error occurred: break out of the while-loop
            }
        }
    } while(FindNextFile(hFind, &fdFile));

    if (GetLastError()!=ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
        printf("ERROR_FINDNEXT");
        retval= ERROR_FINDNEXT;
    }
    FindClose(hFind);
    return retval;
}
```

EDIT: in one of your comments you said it didn't upload all files. The following is a test program to read all files/filenames in a directory. If this succeeds, then the error is in the uploading:

```
int InetPDFtest(void)   // returns 0 upon success
{
    int retval= 0, n= 0;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fdFile;
    HANDLE hFind = NULL;
    char sPath[2048];
    char sDir[]= "C:\\Tmp";

    sprintf(sPath, "%s\\*.*", sDir);

    if ((hFind = FindFirstFile(sPath, &fdFile)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Path not found: [%s]\n", sDir);
        return ERROR_NO_PATH;
    }
    do
    {
        if ((fdFile.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)==0)
        {
            sprintf(sPath, "%s\\%s", sDir, fdFile.cFileName);
            n++;

        }
    } while(FindNextFile(hFind, &fdFile));

    if (GetLastError()!=ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
        printf("ERROR_FINDNEXT");
        retval= ERROR_FINDNEXT;
    }
    else {
        printf("%d files processed\n", n);
    }
    FindClose(hFind);
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: `if ((buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048))== NULL)` sir showing error in this line `invalid conversion from void* to char*`

Comment: And sir is there any need of `static char *type = "text/pdf";` because it is uploading all document of different different formet correctly

Comment: 1. The cast to `(char *)` is required in C++ but not in C. Your project is apparently set to compile C++. No problem, just apply the cast. 2. Whether the type header is necessary I don't know; that's part of the HTTP protocol. If it is necessary you must create it based on the file type you are uploading. Try first leaving it out and see what happens.

Comment: sir dont know how to typecast that line

Comment: Really, you should get a book on C. Type casting is a very simple thing. In your case: `if ((buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048))== NULL)`, that is, you cast the result of `malloc` to a pointer to char.

Comment: aaaww  that was very simple..it is uploding files but not all  now it uploaded ,2421 files out of 2802

Comment: Then you must get an error/error message from your program. If you don't then there is something wrong on the server side. The only thing not tested is the return value of `FindNextFile`. I added the test to my solution; it is at the end.

Comment: Sir it is uploading 9 files out of 10 files...i have tested it many times it means in multiple of 10 it will reduce one file

Comment: What is the eror message?

Comment: See test function at end of solution.

Comment: Now take my main solution and comment out the `HttpSendRequest`. Check that all files are processed (count `n` and print it at the end). If that works, then the server doesn't accept all POSTs. Do you get an error message? I alos suggest not sending the `Content-Type:` header, unless you provide the correct type.

Comment: `sprintf(buffer, "%sContent-Type: %s\r\n", buffer, type);` and `static char *type = "text/pdf";` i have removed both above and it is giving same result it means there is no need to tell server the type of file.

Comment: So we are back at the full solution, including the `HttpSendRequest` which is not giving an error. It means that all `n` files are posted, but not all files are stored by the server. You must check what happens at the server when it receives a file; the program seems OK now.

Comment: Sir do you know uploading using base64 implementation with appropriate content if yes then how to do it .

Answer (score 1):

Note that `content`, the pdf file's content, is in the particular pdf format. When you do:

```
memcpy(buffer + strlen(buffer),content,lSize);
sprintf(buffer, "%s\r\n", buffer);
```

then the sprintf will stop the printing at the first `\0` (null character).

You should do something like:

```
//print header
sprintf(buffer, "%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%s\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n", boundary, nameForm, filename);
sprintf(buffer, "%sContent-Type: %s\r\n", buffer, type);
sprintf(buffer, "%sContent-Length: %d\r\n", buffer, lSize);

strcat(buffer, "\r\n");
int len= strlen(buffer);                // remember length of header
memcpy(buffer + len, content, lSize);   // append contents
char *buf_tail= buffer+len+lSize;       // start of tail
strcpy(buf_tail, "\r\n");
buf_tail += 2;

strcpy(buf_tail, boundary);
buf_tail += strlen(boundary);
strcpy(buf_tail, "--\r\n");
```

that is, you keep track of the end of the buffer and add data there.

Comment: you are correct Paul Sir but how to correct that code

Comment: sir see above code i made some changes and use your above code but now it is not uploading pdf file

Comment: That is because you insterted the code at the wrong place! When you do `buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048);` and then `strcat`, the bufer still contains garbage! Replace from `memcpy` with the code I provided. And get a book on C as this is a very basic error and an unthougtfull way of applying my solution.

Comment: sorry sir i use malloc function after memcpy but still not any progress can you please currect that code i am trying to made this program since 5 month

Comment: You have removed creating the header. I put that back in my solution

Comment: sir i put it back `buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048);`because it is runtime process stopping if i comment this line of move it after memcpy and i change buffer into buff_tail `BOOL sent = HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buf_tail, strlen(buf_tail));` and copied above your code given  now programm is running and not giving any garbage value but still not uploading pdf file

Comment: programm running not uploading any file and buffer giving garbage value and buf_tail printing --

Comment: Well, Jitender, start using a debugger. I am not your debugger. I pointed out your error and fixed it. If it still not working, it must be somthing else.

Comment: paul sir please help me last night i wasnt sleeping because of this programm.i am working hard on this program

Comment: `buf_tail` is only used to be able to skip the binary PDF content and append the tail. You have created one large chunk of internet information that you want to post. The large chunk is in `buffer` so you must `POST` the `buffer` and not `buf_tail`. The `HttpSendRequest` must be: `sent = HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buffer, len+lSize+strlen(buffer+len+lSize));` Note calculating the length of the buffer: It is the length of the header (`len`) plus the size of the PDF contents (`lSize`) plus the size of the trailer (which starts at the first `buf_tail` we calculated).

Comment: I WANT TO SAY  `#include<Thank you>` Paul sir, it is uploading file now yippy i will be thankfull to you my whole life..............it is uploading file now

Comment: Dont know thank how to say you thank you it is great pleasure to me that i talked with you..............its amazing thank you paul sir

Comment: Please thank me by clicking on the left of my solution to accept the solution (green V appears). That is how this community works. I am happy that it works now.

Comment: Paul Sir i have a different question in this program i am uploading all files of a folder it is working well but there is 2000 files in this folder and while uploading it into server it is uploading only 768 files i dont know where is the problem why it is not uploading all files .I have made some changes in this program.

Comment: 1) please format your code so it is readable. 2) you keep allocating `buffer` and `content` again and again and never `free` it. 3) you don't check the return value of `malloc` so you don't see that you have (probably) ran out of memory. Better to open a new question than to keep clobbering this one.

Comment: Sir it is correctly running and uploading files ....but it is uploading using HTTP  can you please tell me what should i do if i have to upload it with HTTPS

Comment: Sir please help me how to run it with HTTPS

Comment: And while uploading to webserver with HTTP it is showing ERROR_INTERSEND ,ERRO_FINDNEXT